# Designing an experiment for a marketing campaign using Incremental Response Modelling

Tags: cross-validation, modeling, dataset, marketing

I have the following hypothetical question, can anyone provide some clarification?

I'm looking at designing an experiment or modelling what steps can be taken to maximise the Net Incremental Revenue for a 3 month marketing campaign, described below.

The marketing campaign is about sending emails to a database of customers based on their shopping preferences. You send one email per week, with 5 products in each email.

Requirements:

```
1. Create a marketing campaign
2. Send promotional emails to millions of subscribed users
3. Existing data feed with hundreds of products for the following week
4. Each customer must have 5 products in their respective, tailored emails
5. The history for what the customer purchased in the previous weeks is available
6. The campaign must go for 3 months (ie 12 rounds of batch emails)
7. The objective is to find the max(net incremental revenue) 
8. net incremental revenue = net revenue (with campaign) - net revenue (without campaign)
9. Net revenue is the total $ amount of retail sales during that period
10. Each product has a retail cost (r(i)) and a wholesale cost (w(i)) and a discount (d(i)) for each product i.
11. The price of a product is = r(i) - d(i)
```

Limitations:

```
1. There is no history prior to the 3 month campaign (That is the customer data that is available at the start of each week, is not available prior to the start of the campaign - so you are pretty much developing a training set or a learner through this process)
2. A total of 12 batch email jobs can be sent
```

Thoughts ideas anyone?

Answer (score 2):

There are so many ways of approaching this question.

First of all, although you don't say it, you are talking about building predictive models for a direct marketing campaign that would identify, e.g., the top customer deciles or ventiles in terms of the likelihood of a response against which to build a mailing since these top likely responders would form the core of your communication efforts. This is an area that is so well studied and researched in the DM industry that you can practically take published response rates and come up with some quite reasonable estimates for *net incremental revenue* without ever having to actually run a campaign. For instance in credit cards, email response rates are well enough known that if a senior executive sets a target of obtaining $100 million in new customer credit, they would know exactly how many mailings to which customers would achieve that target. If this information is not available to you, then your company really needs to get with the program. There should be little or no mystery about this.

Do you have a customer lifetime value model? This is probably your single best guide to maximizing your revenue as it's a future or *forward looking* view on your customers. If you have a CLTV, then use it as your "stake in the ground" wrt the initial waves of the campaign. On the back end, you should leverage tools such as *Unica* to evaluate the ongoing succes of these campaigns. The weekly nature of the emails will make it hard to quickly integrate out responders from nonresponders for future campaign waves unless response is expected within a few days as opposed to the more typical few weeks or even months.

You have purchase history. I find it surprising that you wouldn't also have information about how responsive your customers are to marketing stimulation. This would give you some index of your customers' *engagment* with your business. You might want to consider partitioning out those customers that are likely to purchase whether they are marketed to or not from those that need the stimulation. This is called *uplift* marketing and can represent a significant cost savings in campaign dollars.

Of course, you have to customize the product offerings as a function of your product set as well as each customer's purchase history. If your business is a typical retail business, then the vast majority of your customers will have a sparse purchase history. The question at this point is do you "microsegment" your millions of customers in a true "one-to-one" sense or do you create segments that would aggregate your customers and tactically target to those segments? This question basically concerns the costs associated with "micro-" or even "nano-" targeting vs using aggregated segments of customers. The aggregated approach will be less costly, of course.

Then, there are questions concerning the sequence of recent purchases. It is possible to make a prediction of what a next purchase might be based on a customer's (or segment) past history. This could boil down to a *k-nearest neighbor* type recommendation problem for each customer (or segment).

Finally, your question is specific or granular enough that it sounds like you expect someone to write an optimization function for you. That's not what this site is about or what anyone responding to a question here is expected to deliver.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have the answer.

Possibly doing an A/B test with each type of product, so partitioning the customers out and sending a combination of different types of products, to see what the response rate is for each product. The higher the response rate, for a particular product, it should be included for the following week.

Additionally looking at developing a classifier that uses historical information from previous purchases to *correct* the rates you're getting.